# How to determine the log bins needed for recovery when the --master-data=2 option is not used in mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

When the `--master-data=2` option is used in the `mysqldump` command, it displays information indicating which log bin should be used to initiate the recovery process. It provides something similar to the following:

```
--
-- Position to start replication or point-in-time recovery from
--

-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000011', MASTER_LOG_POS=411;
```

Is there a way to determine this information when the --master-data=2 option is not used? How can I accurately identify the necessary log bins for the recovery process?

Answer (score 0):

The way to determine it if `--master-data` is not used is to make a new backup, and this time use the `--master-data` option.

There is no way to infer the binary log coordinates from a backup that does not have them.

Well, you can make a guess based on timestamps, but it won't be precise. You'll either be missing some events, or else some will be replayed twice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've found a way. **I am not a MySQL expert, so I would be glad if someone told me if I am right.**

The last line of mysql dump show when the backup has finished.

```
[root@mysql1 backup]# tail -1 /backup/alldbs.sql
-- Dump completed on 2023-06-05 15:03:36
[root@mysql1 backup]#
```

So, I don't need to know which `log bin` I need to start a recovery (I am not creating a replication, only working with backup and recover in the same server). I mean, I don't need to recover the log bins like it:

```
[root@mysql1 backup]# cd /dados/logbin/
[root@mysql1 logbin]# mysqlbinlog binlog.000090 binlog.000091 ... |mysql -u root -ppassword
```

I can issue the following command based in the timestamp of mysql dump backup information (last line) and call all available log bins (mysql-bin.0*). MySQL will check wich log bins I need.

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2023-06-05 15:03:36" \
            /dados/logbin/mysql-bin.0* \
            | mysql -u root -ppassword
```

At least in my test, it has worked. Not sure in a real envoriment.